# Error when running tests after upgrading to Angular 15 (from Angular 14)

Tags: angular, testing, components

I recently upgraded my Angular project from version 14 to version 15. After the upgrade, when I try to run my tests using the command ** ng test --project web-components**, I encounter the following error:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Compilation cannot be undefined.
    at webpackOptions.entry (.../find-tests-plugin.js:70:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I believe this error is related to the find-tests-plugin.js file provided by the Angular builder, which is a dependency installed with Angular 15.

I suspect that there might be an incompatibility between Angular 15 and the @angular-devkit/build-angular package. I have already tried updating the package to the latest version compatible with Angular 15 using the command npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@15--save-dev, but the error still persists.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully run the tests in Angular 15. Thank you!

[Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxYfL.jpg)

I know that there is a message that said that cannot be undefined but with version 14 i don't have that problem. The file is part of the @angular-devkit/build-angular

[find-tests-plugin.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7AaN.jpg)

The karma-ci.conf.js used for the test is this (i don't find any error)

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false,
      captureConsole: false,
      jasmine: {
        random: false,
      },
    },
    reporters: ['dots', 'coverage'],
    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'text-summary',
      dir: '../../coverage/web-components',
      subdir: '.',
      check: {
        emitWarning: false,
        global: {
          statements: 35,
          branches: 22,
          functions: 31,
          lines: 35,
        },
      },
      watermarks: {
        statements: [35],
        branches: [22],
        functions: [31],
        lines: [35],
      },
      reporters: [{ type: 'html' }, { type: 'text-summary' }],
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
    autoWatch: false,
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
      },
    },
  });
};
```